# Dual of a LP with a variable restricted to be negative

Tags: linear-programming, dual

I have to find the dual of following LP:

Minimize    $ x_1 + x_2 + x_3$

subject to

$4x_1 + 8x_2 \geq3$

$7x_2 + 4x_3 \leq 6$

$3x_1 - 2x_2 + 5x_3 = 7$

$x_1 \leq 0, x_2 \geq 0, x_3$ is unrestricted

I changed it into a canonical form,changed the maximum to minimum, coefficients of objective function into the value of the  constraints and took the transpose of the coefficient matrix,for the $x_3$, I let $x_3 =x_3^{'} - x_3^{''}$ where both $x_3^{'}$ & $x_3^{''}$ are positive. For equality in the constraints, I split it into $\geq$ and $\leq$.

I also managed to satisfy the number of constraints and variables in the prime and dual. I noticed after all this steps that, $x_1$ was restricted to be negative.

So should I introduce a new variable $x_1^{'} =-x_1$?

If not, how do I address it?

Comment: Is this for homework? Usually software converts into canonical form for you.

Comment: No. I was trying some previous year question papers. But I'm not sure what to do with $x_1$

Comment: @AY, welcome to ORSE. Based on the relation between the primal and dual, the sign of the dual variables is determined by the sign of its corresponding primal constraint and vice versa.

In your case, to convert the primal to dual, you need to declare three new variables corresponding to each constraint. Now, if you have a primal variable with the sign $\leq 0$, here $x_{1}$, whose constraint sign would be $\geq C_{1}$.

Comment: Would you please, what exactly you mean by, (So should I introduce a new variable $x^′_1=−x_1$?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get that last part where constraint sign would be $\geq C_1$

Comment: @A.Omidi I thought that inorder to convert a primal to a dual, all the variables should be $\geq 0$. Since $x_1$ was given negative, I thought maybe I could introduce the negative of $x_1$ as a new variable so that the new variable would be positive, and then rewrite the primal in the form of that new variable. But I'm not even sure if this is a correct approach or even a necessary one

Comment: @AY, you can transform any LP model into its dual form. I recommend trying to write the dual of your problem based on [primal-dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Duality) relations.